# Is there way to get access to the JavaScriptCore context inside iOS from React Native native module?

Tags: ios, react-native-ios, javascriptcore

I would like to use the JSC context of the React Native on iOS.

I found a couple of mentions but looks like it's not a case anymore
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14041
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1618#issuecomment-112275871

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you have to use the native module system of React Native to wrap the native context into a JS-accessible proxy. See the following guides for reference:

- [iOS Native Modules](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios)
- [Creating a Native Module in React Native](https://medium.com/wix-engineering/creating-a-native-module-in-react-native-93bab0123e46)

Comment: How can I get access to the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore/jscontext ?

Comment: For example, earlier it was possible with `JSContext *context =  [mBridge jsContext];` but it's not the case anymore.